# Reinstalling Xcode on Mountain Lion after upgrading from Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I'm running OSX 10.8. My Mac had Snow Leopard when I got it, but I have since upgraded to Lion and then Mountain Lion. I'm trying to get my Ruby on Rails environment set up, and when I run Homebrew's "brew doctor" command, I get this:

```
Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please install the CLT or Xcode 5.0.1.

Warning: Your compilers are different from the standard versions for your Xcode.
If you have Xcode 4.3 or newer, you should install the Command Line Tools for
Xcode from within Xcode's Download preferences.
Otherwise, you should reinstall Xcode.
```

So I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode (now have v 5.0.2) and the command line tools, and I'm still getting the same messages. I've tried doing:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=xcodedir
```

But I get this in response:

```
sudo: /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `which gcc` to figure out which gcc you are using.

Then run `which -a gcc` to see all the gcc's that you have installed.

You'll probably find that you're using the osx version and that changing your path ordering in shell config, eg. `bash.rc` will fix this `brew doctor` error.